# how to make that the each index of the column vector should be repeated only twice

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix (10,20,4) and a column vector (10). I have made a matrix, where each row will choose only one index from the column vector. But, how to make that the each index of the column vector should be repeated only twice.

```
   userDistance=randint(10,20,4);
    K_max=20;
    NN=4;

    for nn=1:NN
        for ue=1:K_max
            temp = userDistances(:,ue,nn); 
            [~,sort_temp] = sort(temp,1,'ascend');
            UE_selected(ue,nn)=sort_temp(1);
        end  
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear to me if you are asking for this, but having a column vector with indices `v`, the following code filters out the values that appeared more than twice, keeping the original order:

```
v = randi(5, 1, 15)'
u = unique(v); % different values
A = repmat(v, 1, length(u)) == repmat(u', length(v), 1);
B = cumsum(A) .* A; % accumulate ocurrences per row
m = max(B');
output = v(m <= 2) % only those that appeared up to 2 times.
```

Example of execution:

v =

```
 4
 1
 2
 1
 1
 5
 4
 2
 5
 1
 3
 2
 4
 4
 1
```

output =

```
 4
 1
 2
 1
 5
 4
 2
 5
 3
```